# How to Trigger, based on mouse position, variable fonts?

Tags: javascript, java, html, css

I was looking to trigger different sections with a variable font based on my mouse movement.

For the first section, everything looks great, but when I tried to trigger the second section, it does not work as I expected since it is connected to the first one I guess.

I would need to make the section working independently and in the correct way (to have an idea see section one how is reacting in debug mode)

I was wondering what I have to modify in my Javascript code to make my snippet work with all the sections I want, working independently with their respective variable font interaction. Any ideas?

```
  var x = e.pageX - $(this).offset().left;
  var y = e.pageY;
  var $tlSquare = $('.division--top.division--left');
  var $trSquare = $('.division--top.division--right');
  var $blSquare = $('.division--bottom.division--left');
  var $brSquare = $('.division--bottom.division--right');
  var squareWidth = $(this).width(),
    squareHeight = $(this).height();

  $tlSquare.width(x).height(y);
  $trSquare.width(squareWidth - x).height(y);
  $blSquare.width(x).height(squareHeight - y);
  $brSquare.width(squareWidth - x).height(squareHeight - y);

  stretchLetter(false);
});


stretchLetter(false);

$('.square').on('mouseleave', function() {
  $('.division').width('50%').height('50%');
  $('.letter').css('transform', '');
  stretchLetter(false);
});

function stretchLetter(animation) {
  $('.letter').each(function() {
    var parentWidth = $(this).parent().width();
    var parentHeight = $(this).parent().height();
    var thisWidth = $(this).width();
    var thisHeight = $(this).height();
    var widthPercent = parentWidth / thisWidth;
    var heightPercent = parentHeight / thisHeight;
    var timing = animation == true ? .5 : 0;

    TweenMax.to($(this), timing, {
      scaleX: widthPercent,
      scaleY: heightPercent
    })
    //$(this).css('transform', 'scalex('+ widthPercent +') scaley('+ heightPercent +')');
  });
}
```

```
body,
html {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: helvetica;
}

section {
  height: 200px;
  background: blue;
  color: white;
  font-size: 28px;
}

.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  /*justify-content: flex-end;*/
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  //background-color: blue;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.square {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 100vh;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: black;
}

.square-2 {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 100vh;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: yellow;
}

.division {
  //display: flex;
  //align-items: center;
  //justify-content: center;
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
  //background-color: red;
  //border: 1px solid white;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.letter {
  cursor: -webkit-grab;
  cursor: grab;
}

.letter {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 50vh;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  line-height: .8;
  transform-origin: top left;
  color: white;
}


/* .division:nth-child(1){
    background-color: blue;
}
.division:nth-child(2){
    background-color: red;
}
.division:nth-child(3){
    background-color: green;
}
.division:nth-child(4){
    background-color: orange;
} */

.circle {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 1px solid white;
  background-color: blue;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```
<section>SECTION-01</section>
<main>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="square">
      <div class="division division--top division--left">
        <div class="letter">L</div>
      </div>
      <div class="division division--top division--right">
        <div class="letter">A</div>
      </div>
      <div class="division division--bottom division--left">
        <div class="letter">S</div>
      </div>
      <div class="division division--bottom division--right">
        <div class="letter">T</div>
      </div>
    </div>
</main>
  <section>SECTION-02</section>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="square">
      <div class="division division--top division--left">
        <div class="letter">F</div>
      </div>
      <div class="division division--top division--right">
        <div class="letter">A</div>
      </div>
      <div class="division division--bottom division--left">
        <div class="letter">S</div>
      </div>
      <div class="division division--bottom division--right">
        <div class="letter">T</div>
      </div>
    </div>
</main>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/2.0.2/TweenMax.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/CAT999/ohaf61qp/5/

Answer (score 2):

Updated the snippet to work on individual block. I hope this will be helpful

```js
var $ = jQuery
$('.square').on('mousemove', function(e) {
  var x = e.pageX - $(this).offset().left;
  var y = e.pageY;
  var $tlSquare = $(this).find('.division--top.division--left');
  var $trSquare = $(this).find('.division--top.division--right');
  var $blSquare = $(this).find('.division--bottom.division--left');
  var $brSquare = $(this).find('.division--bottom.division--right');

  var squareWidth = $(this).width(),
    squareHeight = $(this).height();

  $tlSquare.width(x).height(y);
  $trSquare.width(squareWidth - x).height(y);
  $blSquare.width(x).height(squareHeight - y);
  $brSquare.width(squareWidth - x).height(squareHeight - y);
  const childrens = $(this).children().children();
  stretchLetter(false, childrens);
});


/* stretchLetter(false); */

$('.square').on('mouseleave', function() {
  const child = $(this).children();
  child.each(function() {
    $(this).width('50%').height('50%');
  })
  child.children().each(function() {

    $(this).css('transform', '');
  })
  const childrens = $(this).children().children();
  stretchLetter(false, childrens);
});

function stretchLetter(animation, el) {
  el.each(function() {
    var parentWidth = $(this).parent().width();
    var parentHeight = $(this).parent().height();
    var thisWidth = $(this).width();
    var thisHeight = $(this).height();

    var widthPercent = parentWidth / thisWidth;
    var heightPercent = parentHeight / thisHeight;

    var timing = animation == true ? .5 : 0;

    TweenMax.to($(this), timing, {
      scaleX: widthPercent,
      scaleY: heightPercent
    })
    //$(this).css('transform', 'scalex('+ widthPercent +') scaley('+ heightPercent +')');
  });
}
$(document).ready(function() {
  const el = $(".square")
    .children()
    .children();
  stretchLetter(false, el);
});
```

```css
body,
html {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: helvetica;
}

section {
  height: 200px;
  background: blue;
  color: white;
  font-size: 28px;
}

.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  /*justify-content: flex-end;*/
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  //background-color: blue;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.square {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 100vh;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: black;

}

.square-2 {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 100vh;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: yellow;

}

.division {
  //display: flex;
  //align-items: center;
  //justify-content: center;
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
  //background-color: red;
  //border: 1px solid white;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.letter {
  cursor: -webkit-grab;
  cursor: grab;
}

.letter {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 50vh;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  line-height: .8;
  transform-origin: top left;
  color: white;
}


/* .division:nth-child(1){
 background-color: blue;
}
.division:nth-child(2){
 background-color: red;
}
.division:nth-child(3){
 background-color: green;
}
.division:nth-child(4){
 background-color: orange;
} */

.circle {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 1px solid white;
  background-color: blue;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section>SECTION-01</section>
<main>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="square">
      <div class="division division--top division--left">
        <div class="letter">L</div>
      </div>
      <div class="division division--top division--right">
        <div class="letter">A</div>
      </div>

      <div class="division division--bottom division--left">
        <div class="letter">S</div>
      </div>
      <div class="division division--bottom division--right">
        <div class="letter">T</div>
      </div>
    </div>
</main>
<section>SECTION-02</section>



<!--FOR SINGLE USE THIS ONE <div class="wrapper">
 <div class="square">
  <div class="division division--top division--left">
   <div class="letter">M</div>
  </div>
  <div class="division division--top division--right">
   <div class="letter">A</div>
  </div>
  <div class="division division--bottom division--left">
   <div class="letter">T</div>
  </div>
  <div class="division division--bottom division--right">
   <div class="letter">T</div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div-->




<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="square">
    <div class="division division--top division--left">
      <div class="letter">F</div>
    </div>
    <div class="division division--top division--right">
      <div class="letter">A</div>
    </div>

    <div class="division division--bottom division--left">
      <div class="letter">S</div>
    </div>
    <div class="division division--bottom division--right">
      <div class="letter">T</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  </main>






  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/2.0.2/TweenMax.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: many thanks but still there is some issue, unfortunately. Did you know why the initial position is displayed not correctly now that you updated the code? The letter-spacing is looking different, but when the mouse-enter the text is shown correctly again..                                                <br>Also the second section issue is still the same issue and the variable font is not displayed correctly and not reacting as section one

Comment: It's just a workaround. Can you add the expected and initial images

Comment: Sure.    here the epected how it should look [https://pasteboard.co/IUE4tv7.png ]  and here the initial before mouse-enter [https://pasteboard.co/IUE4M8n.png ]

Comment: @CATT sorry for the late reply, the issue was in your code, you run the code when document loads, but I missed to run it. the issue is now fixed you can now check the updated snippet. Just add `$(document).ready(function() {
  const el = $(".square")
    .children()
    .children();
  stretchLetter(false, el);
});` to the end of the script.